# How to process multiple files based on the date in their names

Tags: python, list, loops, file, if-statement

Let's asume I have a structure like this:

```
Folder1
       `XX_20201212.txt`
Folder1
       `XX_20201212.txt`
Folder1
       `XX_20201212.txt`
```

My current script collects the 3 files in each folder, processes them and makes 1 file of it. So right now my scripts does the job for 1 date.

Now lets asume the structure has changed to this:

```
Folder1
       `XX_20201201.txt`
       `XX_20201202.txt`
Folder1
       `YY_20201201.txt`
       `YY_20201202.txt`
Folder1
       `ZZ_20201201.txt`
       `ZZ_20201202.txt`
       `ZZ_20201203.txt`
```

I want my script to do the same now but for multiple dates. I want my script to check if a file has a date in its name which is also present in a list named `missing_dates` and if that file is available in each directory. If so I want to collect it and process it into 1 file. So if we assume `20201201, 20201202 and 20201203` are in `missing_list`. The following needs to happen.

1. The script will process the files of `XX_20201201.txt, YY_20201201.txt` and `ZZ_20201201.txt` into 1 file because that date is present in `missing_dates` **AND** its present in every directory.
2. The script will process the files of `XX_20201202.txt, YY_20201202.txt` and `ZZ_20201202.txt` into 1 file because that date is present in `missing_dates` **AND** its present in every directory..
3. The script will **NOT** process the file of `ZZ_20201203.txt` because that date is not present in every directory even though its present in the `missing_dates.`

So actually shortly said: 3 files with same date (in 3 different directories) with a date that is present in `missing_dates` = proceed

Please note that below code which is proceding the files into 1 file is already working, the underlying problem is that I have to adjust my loop so that it will always process more than 1 date. I dont know how to do that....

**This is the code that reads the files:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(counter_part):
    for file in files:
        date_files= re.search('_(.\d+).', file).group(1) 
        with open(file_path, 'r') as my_file:
            reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter = ',')
            next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                if filter_row(row):                      
                    vehicle_loc_dict[(row[9], location_token(row))].append(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tools in [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) this is fairly easy.

Given:

```
% tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── dir_1
│   ├── XX_20201201.txt
│   └── XX_20201202.txt
├── dir_2
│   ├── YY_20201201.txt
│   └── YY_20201202.txt
└── dir_3
    ├── ZZ_20201201.txt
    ├── ZZ_20201202.txt
    └── ZZ_20201203.txt

3 directories, 7 files
```

You can do:

```
from pathlib import Path

root=Path('/tmp/test')

missing_dates=['20201201']

for fn in (e for e in root.glob('**/*.txt') 
    if e.is_file() and any(d in str(e) for d in missing_dates)):
    print(fn)
    # here do what you mean by 'proceed' with path fn
```

Prints:

```
/tmp/test/dir_2/YY_20201201.txt
/tmp/test/dir_3/ZZ_20201201.txt
/tmp/test/dir_1/XX_20201201.txt
```

Or, you could do:

```
missing_dates=['20201201', '20201202']

for d in missing_dates:
    print(f"processing {d}")
    for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{d}.txt") if e.is_file()):
        print(fn)
        # here do what you mean by 'proceed'
```

Prints:

```
processing 20201201
/tmp/test/dir_2/YY_20201201.txt
/tmp/test/dir_3/ZZ_20201201.txt
/tmp/test/dir_1/XX_20201201.txt
processing 20201202
/tmp/test/dir_2/YY_20201202.txt
/tmp/test/dir_3/ZZ_20201202.txt
/tmp/test/dir_1/XX_20201202.txt
```

If you are only interested in groups of 3, you can do:

```
missing_dates=['20201201', '20201202', '20201203']

for d in missing_dates:
    print(f"processing {d}")
    files=[fn for fn in (e for e in root.glob(f"**/*_{d}.txt") if e.is_file())]
    if len(files)==3:
        print(files)
```

Prints:

```
processing 20201201
[PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_2/YY_20201201.txt'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_3/ZZ_20201201.txt'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_1/XX_20201201.txt')]
processing 20201202
[PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_2/YY_20201202.txt'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_3/ZZ_20201202.txt'), PosixPath('/tmp/test/dir_1/XX_20201202.txt')]
processing 20201203
```

You can do the same thing with `os.walk` and `glob.glob` but it is just more work...

Comment: your code works great. I used your last one with `len(files)=3`. Just a question... how can I be sure that it really proccess 1 file of the same date so it doesnt mix them up?

Comment: I don't understand you question I'm afraid. The glob will only select files with that particular date. The mix up would potentially be in how the files are named and the assumption made in what the recursive glob is selecting in the particular file tree. Example, if you had some files that you renamed `OLD_DONTUSE_20201202.txt` that file will be selected along with the rest from that date. It is up to you to either refine the glob or test the files or make sure the files in the tree are the ones expected. Otherwise I don't know what you mean by 'mix them up'...

Comment: is there a possiblity to private chat so I can tell you what I exactly need?